# RegEx in a PHP mysqli prepared statement query to update numbers (integers) only

Tags: regex, mysqli, numbers, integer, prepared-statement

I'm using RegEx in a MySQLi prepared statement to find any rows that contain only an integer in a particular field. I want to replace those integers with an empty string. I also want to ignore any rows that contain alphabetic characters in that field. However, my syntax seems to be wrong. Here is my PHP code:

```
$Empty = "";
$IntegersOnly = "[0-9]+";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, "UPDATE MyTable set MyField = ? where REGEXP ?");
$bind = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $Empty, $IntegersOnly);
$exec = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

I'm getting the following error at the bind line: `mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given`

So I believe my `$stmt` or `$bind` syntax is wrong.

Please consider that my programming experience is limited. I am hoping to use MySQLi (not `PDO`) and procedural programming (not `OOP`).

I'm using PHP 7 with a recent version of MariaDB, which is equivalent to MySQL

Answer (score 0):

My apologies. I found the mistake. I should have used this:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, "UPDATE MyTable set MyField = ? where MyField REGEXP ?");
```

In other words, I accidentally omitted `MyField` before `REGEXP`.